# Different Newtonsoft.Json dependency resolved for same MassTransit version

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net, nuget, masstransit

When installing MassTransit 7.0.6 in two projects of the same solutions, it seems to require different Newtonsoft.Json versions:

Project A (.net core 3.1 console application):

[image]

Project B (asp.net core 3.1):

[image]

One is targeting 11.0.2 and the other 12.0.3. Masstransit itself is referencing 11.0.2: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit/MassTransit.csproj#L17

How is it possible, that nuget/visual studio resolves or requires two different versions?

Comment: I suspect it's just a matter of ASP.NET Core itself depending on 12.0.3... so the MassTransit dependency resolves to the later version.

Comment: In nuget, dependency is Newtonsoft.Json >= 11.0.2, not exactly equal.

Comment: @Evk thanks for the fast reply. The strange problem is, that under windows everything is running. When deploying on Ubuntu 20.04, it is missing Newtonsoft.Json 12. Very strange.

Comment: Which of the two projects is missing version 12? Also worth checking which version is actually published in Ubuntu case. Quite strange if exactly the same application, while copied from windows to linux as is, starts missing third party dependency.

Comment: Project A is missing the reference. I'm adding it by using `<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />`

Comment: As you seem to have figured out, MassTransit is using 11.0.2 (or later) and something else is pulling the newer version. If you need further assistance, tag me.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson the assembly solved the problem. But I don't get why it is working on my local windows machine, but not on ubuntu 20.04. I've got the same problems with some other references too but referencing them manually, solved the problem. Will write an answer for that.